# Reading values from xsl

Tags: xslt

I have an xml like :

```
 <UserData>
      <UserDataField name="IsShipAllow">true</UserDataField>
      <UserDataField name="OrderType">InHouse</UserDataField>
      <UserDataField name="OrderStockType">INSTOCK</UserDataField>
 </UserData>
```

I want to read the value=INSTOCK of the field when name="OrderStockType"

I have written the xsl as

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="UserData/UserDataField/@name = 'OrderStockType'">
                            <xsl:attribute name="Type">
                                <xsl:value-of select="UserData/UserDataField/@name" />
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:attribute name="Type">FALSE</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Your XSL snippet is useless because we don't know what the context node is at the time it's executed - see: [mcve].

Comment: And what happens? How does it fail? (I assume it fails, or you wouldn't be asking the question). And what output do you want to produce?

Comment: It doesn't error out, no value is picked . I used to xpath instead as Zharro suggested. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use xsl for getting values from XML? [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) can do it much easier. Try `/UserData/UserDataField[@name='OrderStockType']`.